# Does this basement HVAC register/vent plan make sense?

Tags: hvac, basement, canada

Located in Ontario Canada, so winter tend to be cold and summer mild.

We are finishing basement, the finished area is about 900 square feet.

We have came up with the following locations and numbers for the supply and return vents. The supply vents all uses 5" round metal ducts, and are located in the ceiling. I will need to add some return vents after framing is done, and planning to put them at the floor level. The return vents will use 6" round metal ducts where needed (Very hard to find 7" or 8" round metal ducts here in homedepot Canada).

Please see layout of the basement and locations of the ducts below:

[image: Text]

Now few questions.

1. Do I have too many supply ducts in the living room? Is supply vent D really needed?
2. For the living room return duct A, can I get away with a 6" duct? Or do I need a either a second return vent, or somehow use 8" ducts?
3. Is return duct A location okay? My concern is that it is bit far from the bathroom and majority of the living room. It is the most convenient location though due to existing ductwork.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.